f string vs .format in manipulating a file name
I am trying to manipulate a file name to remove an underscore.
final_name = '{0}{1}{2}_{4}_new'.format(*filename.split('_'))

The filename is something like - 2024_10_10_091530_xyz_new.txt and the code does work fine and I can get the desired result 20241010_xyz_new as the final name.
How would I be able to get the same result using an f-string?

You mean final_name = "{0}{1}{2}_{4}_{5}".format(*filename.split("_"))?

You can't "spread" the output of filename.split across the fields in an f-string like you can across the arguments of format.

This is a case where format() is the best tool for the job. To use an f-string you need a 2-step approach as described by @ShadowRanger

Generally you would two-line it, one to split and unpack, one to use the unpacked names:
# Limit to 5 splits to avoid oversplitting when suffix name has additional
# underscores you don't care about
year, month, day, _, name, _ = filename.split('_', 5)
final_name = f'{year}{month}{day}_{name}_new'

The first line just splits it up and unpacks the result (ignoring the two components of the original name we don't care about, but still listing them to ensure they actually exist as expected). Additional underscores are allowed to exist in the ignored suffix, we avoid them causing unpacking exceptions (and speed up the split very slightly by avoiding unnecessary work looking for them) by explicitly limiting to no more than five splits.
After that, we have access to all of them as named variables (making the intent of the code rather more obvious) and can use those names in the f-string placeholders.
Note that this code is rather brittle as written. We claim it's getting year, month, day, etc., but all we really checked is the underscore count is at least five (if it was less than five, the unpacking would die with an exception). This is a case where a more rigorous check via a regex might help you, e.g.:
import re  # At top of file

# Adjust regex to be more or less permissive as appropriate, e.g.
# allowing fewer digits in date components if that's expected,
# allowing wider ranger of characters in "name" component, etc.
if m := re.fullmatch(r'(\d{4})_(\d{2})_(\d{2})_\d{6}_([a-z]+)_new.txt', filename):
    year, month, day, name = m.groups()
    final_name = f'{year}{month}{day}_{name}_new'
else:
    # Not in expected form handle error here


Like this:
filename = "2024_10_10_091530_xyz_new.txt"
parts = filename.split('_')
final_name = f"{''.join(parts[:3])}_{parts[4]}_new"
print(final_name)  
# Output: 20241010_xyz_new


Assuming the date part has constant width
fn = '2024_10_10_091530_xyz_new.txt'
print(f"{fn[0:4]}{fn[5:7]}{fn[8:10]}{fn[17:]}")

Result
20241010_xyz_new.txt

Also this convoluted one
print(f"{''.join([c for i,c in enumerate(fn[:]) if i not in [4,7,10] and (i < 11 or i > 16)])}")


Use the walrus:
>>> filename = '2024_10_10_091530_xyz_new.txt'
>>> f'{(a:=filename.split('_'))[0]}{a[1]}{a[2]}_{a[4]}_{a[5]}'
'20241010_xyz_new.txt'


While this is legal, there's little reason to do it this way. It ends up uglier than the .format approach, without adding anything readability-wise (harming readability IMO).

@ShadowRanger Is it really so much worse than all the other solutions here which use f-strings that it's the only one that deserves a downvote? It's clearly a lot more readable than most of those. I sometimes wonder whether any use of the walrus operator risks gaining downvotes simply because some people just don't like it. I bet I'd get no downvotes if I gave an almost identical answer like this instead: a = filename.split('_'); f'{a[0]}{a[1]}{a[2]}_{a[4]}_{a[5]}'.

It doesn't deserve a downvote (I didn't vote up or down; I generally only downvote for wrong, wildly inefficient, or gratuitously non-idiomatic answers; this is nonidiomatic, but the question asked for it, so that's not a problem, and it's correct and performant). It's answering the question in the most straightforward way, and it's fully correct, I was just pointing out that if you're looking for alternatives to str.format for this scenario, you probably are trying to find something cleaner. If you like f-strings for the sake of f-strings, this is fine, go nuts, it's just not cleaner.

@ShadowRanger Thanks for the reasoned response. I guess the OP is the best one to judge. I usually take claims about "readability" with a large pinch of salt - in practice, consistency is far more valuable. In my own code, I avoid using format as much as possible as it's so slow and clunky. The % syntax is often much more elegant (esp. with dicts). I actually considered posting a regexp solution with named groups so the groupdict could be used in combination with %. If you're looking for alternatives, the old-school syntax is sometimes much better than f-strings or format.
